# Aforge VideoSourcePlayer is too slow

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, video-streaming, picturebox, aforge

I am receiving continuous frames from a video device which I convert into image and then play them as live video on WPF application. I have used picture box control for this purpose. It works for 1 or two video streams. But as soon as I add more. It shows clear lag in performance and frames per second reduce drastically.

I then tried using Aforge's `VideoSourcePlayer` control. I implemented IVideoSource that receives images and pushes them to `VideoSourcePlayer`  via `NewFrame?.Invoke(this, new NewFrameEventArgs(image))` and I am expecting them to be played seemlessly. Which is not the case. It is very laggy even for one video stream.

My question is: Is there something wrong with my approach?

Is there any other open source control that can help me with this problem?